# Undefined variable issue

Tags: php, variables

There are 3 compilation errors in the **init.php** code:

> Undefined variable $ind
>
> Undefined variable $popsize
>
> Undefined variable $chrom

How to solve this issue in the proper way?

**main.php**

```
include_once 'init.php';

class Individual {
    public $genes = array();
    //...
}

class Population {
    public $ind = array();
    public $ind_ptr;
    public function setIndPtr(Individual $ind) {
        $this->ind_ptr = $ind;
    }   
}

$popsize = 10;
$chrom = 5;
$pop = new Population();
$pop_ptr = new Population();

$pop = init(pop_ptr);
```

**init.php**

```
 function init(Population $pop_ptr) {
      $pop_ptr->setIndPtr($ind[0]);  
      for ($i = 0 ; $i < $popsize ; $i++) { 
        for ($j = 0; $j < $chrom; $j++) {
          $d = rand(0,1);
          if($d >= 0.5) {
             $pop_ptr->ind_ptr->genes[$j] = 1;
          }
          else {
             $pop_ptr->ind_ptr->genes[$j] = 0;
          } 
        }
        $pop_ptr->setIndPtr($ind[$i+1]);
      }
      $pop_ptr->setIndPtr($ind[0]);

      return $pop_ptr;
  }
```

Comment: Your errors say everything - there is no such array like "$ind" and $popsize and $chrom are defined in another scope. You can make them global but better way is pass them through parameter to init function.

Comment: @Cyprian: Ok,init($pop_ptr,$popsize,$chrom) helped removing 2nd and 3rd warning messages. But $ind is defined inside pop_ptr (class Population). Why it cannot be seen in init?

Comment: because "ind" is property of pop_ptr. So if you want to refer to this variable you do that in this way: $pop_ptr->ind[0] (not $ind[0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a matter of scope: Variables are not shared over files, unless you make them global!

(Badly explained) variables such as

inc.php

```
$a=1;
```

main.php

```
include "inc.php";
print $a
```

would work

however

inc.php

```
function func()
{
 $a=1;
}
```

main.php

```
include "inc.php";
func();
print $a;
```

a is not available.

Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Ok,init($pop_ptr,$popsize,$chrom) helped removing 2nd and 3rd warning messages. But $ind is defined inside pop_ptr. Why it cannot be seen and how to solve this problem? Do I need to pass it to the function 'init' as well?

Comment: Variables *are* shared "across included files".

Comment: @Core Xii: I know my question is very basic. But still I don't understand why 'ind' cannot be seen in 'init' function, if I'm passing 'pop_ptr (Population class). 'ind' is defined inside the Population class.

Comment: You can access ind with $pop_ptr->ind;  Because it is defined in a Class, you can can access the Member via the Instance of the Class or make the member static.

Comment: Because ind is contained within a class, its not "ind" in its own right, and yes, sorry they are over included files, but func() { $a=1; } will not let $a be seen inside say func2(){ print $a; } it is a matter of scope..

Comment: @pce: $pop_ptr->setIndPtr($pop_ptr->$ind[0]); Why it says that '$ind = null'?? It is defined as $ind = array() inside the Population class.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables in function scope need to be declared explicitly **global** before use:

```
<?php
function foo()
    {
    global $global_variable_from_outside_function_scope;
    $global_variable_from_outside_function_scope += 1;
    }
```

As for `$ind`, there's no such variable there. You want something more akin to `$pop_ptr -> ind`. Read the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/) again on classes, scope, etc..

Comment: $pop_ptr->setIndPtr($pop_ptr->$ind[0]); Why it says that '$ind = null'?? It is defined as $ind = array() inside the Population class.

Comment: When accessing object properties, you don't use the `$` dollar sign. Just `$pop_ptr -> ind[0]`.